# Difference between Adobe Reader 8.1.3 and 9.2

Tags: adobe-reader

What is the difference between Adobe Reader 8.1.3 and 9.2? When I go to the Adobe Reader download page I may choose one or the other. It says 9.2 includes Acrobat.com on Adobe AIR, but I don't know what that means.

Why would I choose 8.1.3 over 9.2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Progress!

That's about it... Other than that - whatever newer features are in the latest version of Adobe will be supported... All I can quickly find is:

```
* Submit Adobe PDF forms that are created with fillable form fields in such applications as Adobe Acrobat Professional and Adobe Form Designer
* Play back a variety of embedded multimedia content, such as QuickTime and MP3 files
* Read and organize high-fidelity eBooks
* Activate search and accessibility capabilities built into your PDF files
* Display Adobe Photoshop? Album slide shows and electronic cards and export images for online photo processing (online photo services vary regionally)
```

Also, as Nick points out in the comments, also general security updates.

Comment: Hopefully security improvements, Adobe Acrobat and Flash products continue to be exploitable components.

Comment: @Nick +1! of course - I will add to my answer.

Comment: Why would Adobe still offer version 8?

Comment: It may be that the newest version does not support an operating system or configuration that a previous version does.